# Why does .gitattributes not override core.autocrlf configuration on Linux?

Tags: git, carriage-return, line-endings, eol, linefeed

While setting up Git for a project, I've noticed that the line-ending normalization works a bit different on Linux and on Windows.

As I understand the Git documentation on this subject, the behavior on Windows is the correct one. Specifically, when a `.gitattributes` file is present, it should override the `core.autocrlf` setting.

The following table shows the results of some experimentation I've done. The two left-most columns shows the `.gitattributes` file and the `core.autocrlf` setting. The other columns shows the result of the following `git` commands:

1. `git rm --cached <file>` (force next checkout to perform line normalization handling).
2. `git checkout HEAD -- <file>` (checkout the file, applying line ending normalization)
3. `git ls-files --eol <file>` (check the line endings in the working tree)

```
+----------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| .gitattributes | core.autocrlf | Linux 2.7.2 | Linux 2.11.0 | Linux 2.16.2 | Windows 2.12.2.windows.2 | Windows 2.16.1.windows.1 |
|                |               |             |              |              |                          |                          |
+----------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| None           | true          | w/crlf      | w/crlf       | w/crlf       | w/crlf                   | w/crlf                   |
|                |               |             |              |              |                          |                          |
+----------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| None           | false         | w/lf        | w/lf         | w/lf         | w/lf                     | w/lf                     |
|                |               |             |              |              |                          |                          |
+----------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| * text=auto    | true          | w/crlf      | w/crlf       | w/crlf       | w/crlf                   | w/crlf                   |
|                |               |             |              |              |                          |                          |
+----------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| * text=auto    | false         | w/lf        | w/lf         | w/lf         | w/crlf                   | w/crlf                   |
|                |               |             |              |              |                          |                          |
+----------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| * text=auto    | true          | w/crlf      | w/crlf       | w/crlf       | w/crlf                   | w/crlf                   |
|   test text    |               |             |              |              |                          |                          |
|                |               |             |              |              |                          |                          |
+----------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| * text=auto    | false         | w/lf        | w/lf         | w/lf         | w/crlf                   | w/crlf                   |
|   test text    |               |             |              |              |                          |                          |
|                |               |             |              |              |                          |                          |
+----------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

As you can see, on Linux, it seems that the `core.autocrlf`settings has effect, even when a `.gitattributes`file is present.

I'd like some help to determine whether this is actually a bug.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the misunderstanding comes from interpreting the text attribute as meaning the same thing as the autocrlf config setting.

From the `gitattributes` docs (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes):

> This attribute enables and controls end-of-line normalization. When a text file is normalized, its line endings are converted to LF in the repository. **To control what line ending style is used in the working directory, use the eol attribute for a single file and the core.eol configuration variable for all text files. Note that core.autocrlf overrides core.eol**

(Emphasis added.)

So if you want to use attributes to control the line ending you get in the work tree, you need to set the eol attribute (not merely the text attributes).

In fact there are a couple attributes and a couple config options involved in how line endings are handled, and there *are* differences (by design) in the default behavior between Windows and *nix.  From the `git config` docs (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> **core.eol**
>
> Sets the line ending type to use in the working directory for files that have the text property set when core.autocrlf is false. *Alternatives are lf, crlf and native, which uses the platform’s native line ending. The default value is native*

So, to answer your question: no, what you've described is not a bug.

Comment: I'm still consufed. According to your explanation, what is the reason that I still get CRLF on Windows, even if I set core.autocrlf to "false". It's supposed to overwrite core.eol, right?

Comment: @eversceptic - that is what the gitattributes docs say, but at best that has to be interpreted in light of the definitions of core.eol and core.autocrlf (and at worst - and imo - the gitattributes doc is being sloppy where it only means to point out that the eol setting may not be definitive).  Read the core.eol doc snipped above.  It is what is used when autocrlf is false.

Answer (score 1):

Note: the .gitattributes documentation has been updated with Git 2.21 (Feb. 2019)

See [commit c9446f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9446f0504e4b785758eed0b63c7e00c1b7091ba), [commit 2b68085](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b6808531a5b038a0f780af4f8b92c4b27cdf010) (29 Jan 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
Helped-by: [Torsten Bögershausen (`tboegi`)](https://github.com/tboegi).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 13e2630](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13e263095b55c88b7af86c3c88f8b0f937eb4d5c), 07 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### `doc/gitattributes`: clarify "`autocrlf` overrides `eol`"
>
> We only override `core.eol` with `core.autocrlf` when the latter is set to
>   something besides "`false`".
>   Let's make this more clear, and point the reader to the `git-config` definitions, which discuss this in more detail.
>
> Note that setting `core.autocrlf` to `true` or `input` overrides
>   `core.eol` (see the definitions of those options in `git-config`).

And that refers back to [Mark Adelsberger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49154646/6309)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49154646/6309) regarding [`core.eol` config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coreeol).
But this has changed with Git 2.21:

> ### `docs/config`: clarify "text property" in `core.eol`
>
> ```
> `core.eol`:
> ```
>
> Sets the line ending type to use in the working directory for files that are
>    <del>have the `text` property set when `core.autocrlf` is false</del>
>   marked as text (either by having the `text` attribute set, or by having `text=auto` and Git auto-detecting the contents as text).
>
> Alternatives are 'lf', 'crlf' and 'native', which uses the platform's native line ending.
>   The default value is `native`.
>   See `gitattributes` for more information on end-of-line conversion.
>   **Note that this value is ignored if `core.autocrlf` is set to `true` or `input`.**